# How to resove issue access forbidden by rule GET /.well-known/dnt-policy.txt HTTP/1.1

Tags: php

I`m getting following error very frequent

31459#31459: *4840291 access forbidden by rule, client: 188.146.**, server: **, request: "GET /.well-known/dnt-policy.txt HTTP/1.1"

I have nginx webserver

Thanks